How can I fix an error with dropdown menu's background color?
I used Ant design library for dropdown menu. The menu  has white background color. When I opened the project on live server, the code I gave the dropdown menu “background: none” worked successfully. but when I deploy the project to vercel, the dropdown menu has a white background color. how can I fix this error?
When I opened the project on live server, the code I gave the dropdown menu “background: none” worked successfully. but when I deploy the project to vercel, the dropdown menu has a white background color.
